# How to call a c# method after certain period

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have an upload API implemented in Windows Service to upload some files on server. These files come to server from network system anytime.
This upload API has to work after certain intervals and these intervals are stored in database.

The first time the service starts it uploads all the files it has and also get its next time when the method has to run again to upload received files.

For e.g: Service started at 6:30 it uploads the files and it gets its setting from the database that it has to run @ 8:30. This means it should run again after 2 hours. **So what is the correct way to call the upload API after 2 hours.** Current what I am thinking is that I can use a timer control whose interval I will set 2 hours (for e.g.) whose Tick event will call my method.

May be I am doing/thinking something wrong. Please correct me and suggest to me alternatives.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?" Does it just have to function properly, or are there other requirements?

Comment: can you write a windows service or use a Windows Scheduler and have it launch the process..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows Scheduler. It has an API, so you can create tasks to schedule a start of any application or service and there is no need to run your service 24/7.

Comment: I am not getting any API for Task Scheduler